# Design a 256x8 bit RAM using 64 rows and 32 columns programmatically using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I am new to VHDL programming, I am going to do a project on Built-In Self-Repair.In this project am going to design RAMs of different sizes(256 B,8kB,16kB,32kB)etc. and those rams has to be tested using BIST and then they should be repaired.So please help me by giving an example like how to design RAM with 'n' rows and columns

Comment: VHDL has no inherent concept of rows and columns for RAM, so what do you mean by this?  Also, what do you mean by "repair"?  Is boot time replacement of failing cells by some spare cells?  For an VHDL example of RAM inference in VHDL, you can look at [Block and distributed RAM](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.dk/2011/01/block-and-distributed-rams-on-xilinx.html).

Comment: I have implemented a RAM structure using arrays, have referred the link suggested by you. I need to design a RAM with specific rows and columns similar to the hardware architecture of RAM. Repairing means repairing memory under test by replacing row and columns corresponding to faulty locations with spare row and columns(Built In Redundancy Analysis(BIRA) approach.

Answer (score 1):

Start by drawing a block diagram of the RAM at the level of abstraction you want (probably gate-level). Then use VHDL to describe the block diagram.

You should probably limit yourself to a behavioral description, i.e., don't expect to be able to synthesize it. Synthesis for FPGAs usually expects a register-transfer-level description, and synthesis for ASICs is not something I would recommend for a VHDL beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you want to work with SRAM, since this is the simplest case. Also, let's suppose you want to model a RAM with RAM_DEPTH words, and each word is RAM_DATA_WIDTH bits wide. One possible approach is to structure your solution in three modules:

1. One module that holds the RAM bits. This module should have the typical ports for a RAM: clock, reset (optional), write_enable, data_in, data_out. Note that each RAM word should be wide enought to hold the data bits, plus the parity bits, which are redundant bits that will allow yout to correct any errors. You can read about Hamming codes used for memory correction here: http://bit.ly/1dKrjV5. You can see a RAM modilng example from Doulos here: http://bit.ly/1aq1tn9.
2. A second module that loops through all memory locations, fixing them as needed. This should happen right after reset. Note that this will probably take many clock cycles (at least RAM_DEPTH clock cycles). Also note that it won't be implemented as a loop in VHDL. You could implement it using a counter, then use the count value as a read address, pass the data value through a an EDC function, and then write the corrected value back to the RAM module.
3. A top-level entity (optional), that instantiates modules (1) and (2), and coordinates the process. This module could have a 'init_done' pin that will be asserted after the verification and correction take place. This pin should be checked by the modules that use your RAM to know whether it is safe to start using the RAM.

To summarize, you could loop through all memory locations upon reset, fixing them as needed using an error-correcting code. After making sure all memory locations are ok, just assert an 'init_done' signal.